# Iframe i need to adjust the scrolling bars

Tags: iframe

Hello everyone i got an iframe problem and i guess its not rare ok firstly i dont want to resize the window i just want to have an iframe 350x500 and i want the page i call to center atm it only shows the top left of the page i found a lot of solutions to change the div size but cant find a way to adjust the scrollbars.
Thanks in advance

```
    <iframe scrolling="yes" height="1092" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://sms.altasoft.gr/panel/index.asp?lang=el&disp_function=user_login&id=5E8A0F4B-063B-4A7A-81FE-99579AF44BAA">


<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically adjusting the scrollbars can be a difficult task also using jquery due to the nature of the iframe. But in your case I guess you only want to move the position once just to center the meaningful part of the included page, right?

You can wrap the iframe in a div and position it absolutely to the wrapper div, something like that:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #iframe_wrapper {
            width: 530px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        #iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: -140px;
            left: -540px;
            width: 1600px;
            height: 900px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="iframe_wrapper">
        <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no" src="http://sms.altasoft.gr/panel/index.asp?lang=el&disp_function=user_login&id=5E8A0F4B-063B-4A7A-81FE-99579AF44BAA">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Play with the CSS (width and height of the wrapper div, top and left of the iframe) if you want to position and/or show it differently.

And of course you can always dinamically change the css attributes using javascript if you need it.

Comment: i dont want any dinamically i just want the iframe content( the page i load) to center il take a look at your code when i can and thx!!!

Comment: The you can simply use the html and css posted here, it's going to work just fine ;)

Comment: HEY THX IT WORKS!!it looks perfect!! but when i click the connect button inside i want to pop up a new window or change the one we already are can we do that?

Comment: can we make an invisible button on top of the iframe?? so when they click on it they click both buttons and it changes page?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as your final target? The page you want to open is supposed to be the response from the one in the iframe?

Comment: You have no control on the page in the iframe? You should keep in mind the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) then. All you can eventually do is probably detecting when the iframe content is reloaded (after the user logs in) simply using the `load` event, and if the other website sets a cookie you can just redirect the whole page or open another window pointing at the real domain. I think you'd better start a new question if you need any help ;)

Comment: YEAH THAT Sounds perfect how i can do that? ok il make a new question about it ;)